# Why the same ascII code shows different symbols in Excel?

Tags: excel, char, ascii, symbols

It's crazy. I paste the **∞** symbol in Excel in A1 and I put the formula *=code(A1)* in B2.

It shows 63. After I digit *=char(63)* in A2, it shows **?** symbol.

When I test *=(A1=A2)* it's false

If I copy formula and paste value for A2, continue to be false.

Why? How it's possible the same ASCII code shows 2 different symbols?

My version is Excel 2003 and 2010

Answer (score 2):

That is because the character is probably Unicode.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I've discovered that ∞ is related to a unicode symbol from code 221E (ARIAL font), when I used code(.) returns 63.

Comment: I've make some research:

Function CodeUni(s As String) As String
CodeUni = Hex(AscW(Left(s, 1)))
End Function

Then I use CodeUni(A1) and it shows 221E (8734)

In order to do the opposite, uses chrW(8734) in VBA